# urlencode wrong result is not right

Tags: php, urlencode

my php script send this script

```
$this->afterbuyString.="&Zahlart=".urlencode($sOrder->sUserData['additional']['payment']['name']);
```

i have logged the send  details and that show this:

```
Vorkasse%2F%C3%9Cberweisung and result show Vorkasse/Ãœberweisung
```

the right text is Vorkasse/Überweisung

What i am doing wrong? in same script i have other string:

```
$this->afterbuyString .= "&Artikelname_".($i)."=".urlencode((utf8_decode($singleProduct['articlename'])));
```

and that is all ok that send it urlencode Spannungspr%FCfer and sho right Spannungsprüfer

Comment: Your second command is using `utf8_decode` in addition to the `urlencode`. Maybe try that on the first one too?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how the character "Ü" can be encoded. URL encoding simply turns the underlying bytes of whatever encoding the string is in into percent encoded notation. That means, "Ü" in UTF-8 is encoded as the byte sequence `C3 9C`, and that's what you're seeing in the URL. The receiving service then turns that back into a string. Then this string needs to be interpreted as UTF-8 so you'll get the same character "Ü". But apparently it's being interpreted as Latin-1 instead, so you're seeing two different characters in place of "Ü".

Please read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) to get a better grip on the topic and figure out what you're doing wrong.